# Magento 'Select Configurable Attributes' with PHP

Tags: php, magento

I have created new configurable products, and attached their simple products with PHP.

Now when I edit any configurable product I see this screen:

[image: Magento Select Configurable Attributes screen in admin]

So in absence of any Magento documentation, what do I call in PHP to perform the same function as the screen above programatically?

I have seen `$configurable_product->setConfigurableProductsData()` used in some examples, but don't think it is what I need.

Comment: You see that because there is something wrong with your created configurabe product and associated simple products. Check your script again and make sure everything is good in it from magento point of view.

Comment: If I choose one of the attributes, then click on associated products I can see the simple products I have attached. So it looks like the association has worked at a simple product level, it just hasn't set up the attributes on the configurable product.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are right, you are creating the association/link between configurable and child products but what's happening is that when you are creating your configurable product you are not setting up the **setConfigurableAttributesData** that basically setups the superattribute information for that configurable product.

```
    foreach($configAttrCodes as $attrCode){

        $super_attribute= Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('catalog_product',$attrCode->code);
        $configurableAtt = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable_attribute')->setProductAttribute($super_attribute);

        $newAttributes[] = array(
           'id'             => $configurableAtt->getId(),
           'label'          => $configurableAtt->getLabel(),
           'position'       => $super_attribute->getPosition(),
           'values'         => $configurableAtt->getPrices() ? $configProduct->getPrices() : array(),
           'attribute_id'   => $super_attribute->getId(),
           'attribute_code' => $super_attribute->getAttributeCode(),
           'frontend_label' => $super_attribute->getFrontend()->getLabel(),
        );
    }

    $existingAtt = $product->getTypeInstance()->getConfigurableAttributes();

    if(empty($existingAtt) && !empty($newAttributes)){
        $configProduct->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(true);
        $configProduct->setConfigurableAttributesData($newAttributes);
        $configProduct->save();

    }
```

This is small snippet should get you there, let me know if you have any questions or need further help.

Comment: This works, removes the `select configurable attributes` screen, but the products still don't show in the frontend until I click save in the backend

Comment: This could have been down to indexing, but I am now having a problem on a few products telling me `duplicate key exists`

Comment: `$existingAtt = $product->getTypeInstance()->getConfigurableAttributes();`

Comment: Could you paste your full script?

Comment: Sorry my last comment was misleading, I fixed it by setting up `$existingAtt` as above, it was not checking to see if there were already attributes assigned. Thanks again

Comment: how do you get the var $configAttrCodes ?