# Magento PHP: How do I set configurable attributes to a product?

Tags: php, magento

I'm having trouble setting the configurable attributes for a configurable product.
My configurable and simple products are being displayed on the admin side.
[image]
But when I click on a configurable product I see this
[image]

I found this question that's similar to mine
[Magento 'Select Configurable Attributes' with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538790/magento-select-configurable-attributes-with-php)
but I still can't get my config product to be set correctly.

I'm calling my class MagentoProduct and passing "color_of_product" as my attribute code to my "setConfigurableAttributesData" method.
I later save the product by calling "save()".

[image]

```
class MagentoProduct {
private $product;
public function __construct ( ) {
    Mage::init();
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
    $this->product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
}



...
...
...


public function setConfigurableAttributesData($attribute_code){

    $super_attribute= Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('catalog_product',$attribute_code);

    $configurableAtt = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable_attribute')->setProductAttribute($super_attribute);
    $newAttributes[] = array(
       'id'             => $configurableAtt->getId(),
       'label'          => $configurableAtt->getLabel(),
       'position'       => $super_attribute->getPosition(),

       //not 100% if values is correct, what do I set this to?
       'values'         => $configurableAtt->getPrices() ? $this->product->getPrices() : array(),
       'attribute_id'   => $super_attribute->getId(),
       'attribute_code' => $super_attribute->getAttributeCode(),
       'frontend_label' => $super_attribute->getFrontend()->getLabel(),
    );

    echo $configurableAtt->getId()."\n";
    echo $configurableAtt->getLabel()."\n";
    echo  $super_attribute->getPosition()."\n";

   //not 100% if values is correct, what do I set this to?
    $temp = $configurableAtt->getPrices() ? $this->product->getPrices() : array();
    echo $temp."\n";
    echo $super_attribute->getId()."\n";
    echo $super_attribute->getAttributeCode()."\n";
    echo $super_attribute->getFrontend()->getLabel()."\n";


    $this->product->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(true);
    $this->product->setConfigurableAttributesData($newAttributes);

}

...
...

public function save(){
    try{
        $this->product->save();
        }catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
        Mage::log($e->getMessage());
    }   
}
```

}

The echos in my setConfigurableAttributesData function are printing:

Color
0
Array
176
color_of_product
Color

What am I doing wrong?
I've been trying to debug this for hours and can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set configuratble product using **color_of_product** than you have to set this attribute as

1) Global

2) DropDown

3) Apply to **Configurable Product And Simple Product**

4) Set Yes for Use To Create Configurable Product.

If for more you can check **Color** attribute of default magento.

[image]